# Android GUI overlaying

Tags: android, screen, surfaceview

I am new to android. Some time ago I saw application "Cracked Screen". It makes a screenshot of the screen, then adds a transparent "cracked" sprite and display it. Can I do something similar without screenshoting? That is to display the sprite on top of GUI?

P.S.: sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.  Just use a SurfaceView and place the image over it. The image or the layout the image is in should set android:background="@null".  Failing to set a background gives you a default background but setting to null as shown makes it transparent.